# Apache POI problem clone sheet with chart content

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi, clone

I really have success updating cells that are linked with chart, the the graph changes well.

Tested on 4.4.0 and 4.4.1 versions.

But when I used the **cloneSheet** method in order to copy an existing sheet into new one, I get the error when I open it on Excel Office 365, and the charts disappear.

// only this is enough to get the erro.

[image: workbook.cloneSheet(0, newName);]

```
workbook.cloneSheet(0, newName);
```

Well I'm certain that are open, and close the workbooks and sheet in correctly way.

If I do not clone, only update an existing sheet no errors and all work good.

I'm using XSSF workboooks, and do not tested with HFFS.

Comment: Even in last version `4.1.1` the method `cloneSheet` is incomplete. It clones the sheet drawings but it does not clone the charts. So after that both the drawings point to the same chart, which is not allowed. But this is not the only diisadvantage of `cloneSheet`. It does not clone cell comments for example. Try to avoid using this method.

Comment: @AxelRichter then how can copy completely sheet contents? in poi many things is not implemented yet and this case is one of them unfortunately.

Comment: @amir110: Try to avoid the need of copying completely sheet contents when `apache poi` needs to be used. I doubt that `apache poi` ever will be able to catch up with the decades-long lead of `Excel` development. `Excel` development goes further and `apache poi` not even has the stand of 2007 completely. So it is at least more than a decade behindhand.